# Data step merge without using BY(id)

Tags: sas, datastep

I need to merge two datasets like the ones below using a data step:

```
Data have1;
x=1; output;
x=2; output;
x=3; output;
Run;

Data have2;
y = 'A';
z = 'B';
Run;

Data want;
Merge have1 have2;
Run;
```

The result should be the following:

```
x   y   z
1   A   B
2   A   B
3   A   B
```

However when I run the merge SAS only merges the first row and gives me the following:

```
x   y   z
1   A   B
2   
3
```

I know this can be done using a left join, however in order to process the variables in the full dataset I would prefer doing it via a merge. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did variable Z come from?  I think this may be what you want.

```
Data want;
   set have1;
   if _n_ eq 1 then set have2;
   Run;
```

Comment: Thanks that did it. Could you explain what SAS does in the background? The way I am reading this is "If first row in have1 then add to have1 observations from have2". Why does SAS keep adding variables Y and Z for _n_ > 1?

Comment: All variables sourced from dataset (via SET, MERGE, UPDATE etc) are RETAINed.  So since no more observations are read from HAVE2 the values of those variables never change.  This "feature" is what allows MERGE to do one to many joins.

Answer (score 0):

To explain what's going on, what SAS is doing when you bring in data from a dataset and "run out" of rows, it sets all variables that come from that dataset to missing.  This can happen when you do `set a b` (two datasets on the same set statement), or `merge a b` with no `BY`, or `set a; set b;`, though the datastep will terminate when the first dataset runs out of rows in the latter case, so it doesn't matter.

Why @data_null_'s code works, is that

```
if _n_ eq 1 then set b;
```

That never attempts to pull a row that's not there!  It pulls the first row, and then stops trying to pull.  Since all variables coming from a `set` or `merge` are retained automatically, the values are kept even after the first iteration of the data step loop (as long as you don't change them).